# Less than or equal to date in set analysis

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to sum values where the week number is less than or equal to the current week. It works if i just want equal to current week but not if i want less than or equal.

This is what I've tried but nothing works.

```
=Sum({$<Week={"$(<=Week(Today()))"}>}Sales
=Sum({$<Week<={"$(=Week(Today()))"}>}Sales
```

Hopefully someone can help me. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you need operator (less or equal) in the beginning inside quotes.
In dollar expansion $(=expr) you always need equal to evaluate it. Try this:

```
=Sum({$<Week={"<=$(=Week(Today()))"}>}Sales)
```